# Can I apply for a UK tourist visa if I overstayed a Schengen visa 11 years ago?

Tags: uk, schengen, visa-refusals, overstaying, tourist

I overstayed in Italy for 2 years in 2012 (11 years ago). Will I be granted a UK tourist visa?

Comment: Nitpick: Your question body is not asking the same question as your title. Applying for a visa and actually being granted a visa are not the same thing. You can always apply, but you’re generally not guaranteed to be granted a visa.

Answer (score 5):

You can always apply, and you can get a visa, provided you are truthful, tick the appropriate boxes if asked and don't hide any facts

Comment: But getting the visa is not certain at all, best to make a strong case with many reasons for you to return home.

Answer (score -1):

UK has never been in the Shengen area, so this *should* be equivalent to asking for a visa to any other country not in the Shengen area (like eg. Morrocco or Vietnam)

Comment: Except that the UK requires visitor visa applicants to disclose *all* such previous immigration rule breaches, in any country.